# Where can I find a good tutorial/introduction to Live Coding?

Tags: livecoding

I've just stumbled [across](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/technology/8221235.stm) this fascinating article on the BBC website regarding producing music in realtime using a programming language - so called "Live Coding"

I can't seem to find much info on getting started having a go at this sort of stuff, has anyone here heard of Live Coding?

Where do you get the tools / IDE to start doing this stuff?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's available for livecoding music?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392449/whats-available-for-livecoding-music)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Toplap](http://www.toplap.org/index.php/Main_Page) website has links to people, audio, gigs, tools and demos. There are some [introductory exercises](http://www.toplap.org/index.php/Live_Coding_Practice) there which provide some pointers. [Chuck](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/) is an example of one of the programming languages used for this type of coding. [Supercollider](http://supercollider.sourceforge.net/) is an integrated environment and audio programming language that looks pretty good.

Comment: Got Chuck up and running but no luck with SuperCollider on Win 7 :-(

Comment: @Calanus Works for me on win7. Shame that win version has no autocomplete and manual is quite confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac, you can try [impromptu](http://impromptu.moso.com.au/index.html).